# Adjusting raster bounds in Python

Tags: python, raster, rasterio

I have what seems like it should be a simple issue, where all I need to do is adjust the bounds/extents of a given raster so that I can line it up with another. So, I may have a raster whose longitude values go from 0 to 360, and I need to turn it into a raster that goes from -180 to 180. In that example, I could conceivably just cut the array in two at the 180 mark and make a new array stitching the two pieces together in the reverse order, but this is just a special case of my more general question, which is how to automatically align one raster to another so that I can perform calculations across the two.

Comment: Have a look at the [`rasterio.merge` module](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.merge.html)

Answer (score 1):

The GDAL Python bindings work really well for this! Here's a function that I've made and use pretty frequently.

```
from osgeo import gdal

def recoordinate_raster(src):
    # converts src raster to be (-180,180) instead of (0,360)

    gdal.SetConfigOption('CENTER_LONG', '0')

    warp_kwargs = {
        'format': 'GTiff',
        'warpOptions': ['SOURCE_EXTRA=1000']
    }

        dst = 'output_raster.tif'

        gdal.Warp(dst, src, **warp_kwargs)

    gdal.SetConfigOption('CENTER_LONG', None)
```